# Add submit button for searchView Android app

Tags: android, searchview, submit-button

I use searchview in my Android app and I would like to add a button that user presses to start the search. Based on what I read on the Internet, I can use setSubmitButtonEnabled to invoke a submit button instead of putting a button in the layout file. Here's my code:

```
public void setSubmitButtonEnabled (boolean enabled) {

}
```

I put my setSubmitButtonEnabled in the menu inflater as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mylist, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

Apparently I am not doing it right because when I launch my app, I don't see any submit button on the screen. What's missing or what's wrong in my code? Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Comment: Have you tried typing in the search view?  The button shows up only when there is some text to search.

Comment: Yes, I did, but still there isn't any submit button. Or is the submit button supposed to appear in my keypad?

Comment: Thanks for this question, searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The submit button is only shown when the `SearchView` has focus. My workaround for this is to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) (`ABS`), and to edit the source code to allow the submit button to be shown even when the `ActionBar` does not have focus. To do this, follow these steps:

**1. Setup ActionBarSherlock Project**

To do this, follow the link to download `ABS`, then in *Eclipse* (or your favorite IDE), go to `File`->`New`->`Project...`, then choose `Android`->`Android Project from Existing Code`. In the following wizard, navigate to the location of the `actionbarsherlock` folder, then click OK to create the project. Once it is created, you can add it as a library to your existing project by going to `Project`->`Properties`->`Android`, then at the bottom *Library* section, click `Add...`, then choose `actionbarsherlock`. Finally, press OK.

**2. Edit the source**

To fix this issue, you need to edit the file `com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.java`. Once open, navigate to the `updateSubmitButton(boolean)` method, and comment out the code

```
&& hasFocus()
```

Your final method will look like this:

```
private void updateSubmitButton(boolean hasText) {
    int visibility = GONE;
    if (mSubmitButtonEnabled && isSubmitAreaEnabled() //&& hasFocus()
            && (hasText || !mVoiceButtonEnabled)) {
        visibility = VISIBLE;
    }
    mSubmitButton.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Now save, clean your project, and run - you will now get the results you want.

**3. Document your change (optional)**

You can document this change using the [Modified](https://github.com/phil-brown/Modified) annotation, for example:

```
@Modified(author="Phil Brown", summary="Commented out '&& hasFocus()' in order to allow the submit button to be shown without focus to the view.")
private void updateSubmitButton(boolean hasText) {
    ...
}
```